# How to fix '* failed to start daemon error: cannot connect to daemon' on Linux ubuntu

Tags: devices, adb

I had to install the adb tools on my Linux ubuntu with the command line but when I execute the command `adb devices`, I have this return in my terminal :

```
uriel@uriel-linux-ubuntu:~$ adb devices

List of devices attached
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.1000.log
Server had pid: 8577
--- adb starting (pid 8577) ---
adb I 02-28 16:19:21  8577  8577 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 02-28 16:19:21  8577  8577 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2
adb I 02-28 16:19:21  8577  8577 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 02-28 16:19:21  8577  8577 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 02-28 16:19:21  8577  8577 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 02-28 16:19:21  8577  8577 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/home/uriel/.android/adbkey'...
adb I 02-28 16:19:21  8577  8577 adb_auth_host.cpp:391] adb_auth_inotify_init...
adb server killed by remote request

failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon

uriel@uriel-linux-ubuntu:~$
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Providing your OS/product/release will help us better understand your software stack & thus provide better advice. You mention Ubuntu, but not what product (server? desktop? core?) not what release?

Comment: And how you did the "install adb" step?

Comment: Read the logs! First, there is a version disagreement (server v41, client v39) so the server is killed, a v39 server is started, which fails your authentication attempt. .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.